# how to call a private function in object in scala

Tags: scala, function, var

this is for the current score in the class:

```
private var score: Int = 0

def initialiseTest2(): Game = {
  return new Game(List((3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5)), List((4,4,(x: Int) => x+1), (6,3, if(score == 0){ (x: Int) => x+1 }else { (x: Int) => x+3 })), 3,2)
}
```

`def initialiseTest2` is in object and the part where there is the `if(score == 0)` that part I need to call the private var score how can I do that, when I just type score it gives an error saying `not found: value score`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a getter function to return the copy of score. Then, you can access the current score from the tests.

```
object Score {

 private var score: Int = 0

 def currentScore(): Int = score

}
```

Comment: To limit the scope you could even use something like `private[current_package] def currentScore(): Int` to make it available only to classes from the same package or subpackages.